# Error when installing machine python package

Tags: python

I am trying to install the machine library for python on my windows computer. I never had any problem when installing python packages but the machine package doesnt want to get installed. You can see the error that I get on the screenshot. I tried different online solutions but none worked and I always get the same error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxqSf.png)

I tried to install visual studio build tools but it didnt work

Comment: Did you install: setuptools ?
Using: 
     pip install setuptools

Comment: Also please post text in the question (rather than images), and have sufficient info in the question so external links are not needed.